# Delphi7 master detail relations query results in ORA-01036

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7, ora-01036

I'm using Delphi7, Devart's dbExpress driver 4.70.

I drop two TSQLTables (call them `A` and `B`), two TDataSetProviders (`dspA` and `dspB`), two TClientDataSets (`cdsA` and `cdsB`), two TDataSources (`dsA` and `dsB`) and two DBGrids (`gridA` and `gridB`). Everything is set fine. If I set `cdsA.Active` to true I can see the data in `gridA`. The same per `cdsB`.

Now I want to implement the relation

```
A JOIN B ON a = b.
```

The field `a` is the true `A`'s foreing key referred by `B`'s field `b` and `b` is `B`'s primary key too. I set the stuff as follow (I use graphic tools):

```
cdsB.MasterSource := dsA;
cdsB.MasterFields := a;
cdsB.IndexFieldNames := b;
```

When I do `cdsB.Open`, I got this error:

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number".

The field `a` value is always `null` in table A (there is no data). TSQLMonitor reports the following queries:
`Execute: select * from A`

`...`

`Execute: select * from ENTI where (b is NULL)`

`:1 (Number,IN) = <NULL>`

What did I miss, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Edit your question to include the full SQL statement you're executing.

Comment: cdsA is open before you open B?

Comment: Since you're using the designer, double clicking on the MasterFields property in the Object Inspector should launch the ['Field Link Designer'](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/fieldlinkdesigner_xml.html). Also see: [Making the Table a Detail of Another Dataset](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/5datasetmakingthetableadetailofanotherdataset_xml.html)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, yes. I open cdsA first, then cdsB.

Comment: I substitute `TSQLTable B` with `TSQLQuery B`. I set `B` statement as `select * from B where b=:b`. `B.IndexFieldNames`, `B.MasterFields` and `B.MasterSource` remain the same. Well, if I use `TSQLQuery` instead of `TSQLTable` everything work fine. That's weird.

Answer (score 0):

When using Datasnap, you should set the M/D relationship on the source datasets, not the client ones. It will create a "dataset field" in the master client dataset. You then assign this field to the child client dataset. This approach is also more perfomant.

Anyway it should work as well, it looks there is something wrong with your SQL.